# Проблема с pip, no module 'pip'

Tags: python

Проблема такая, нужно было установить pyinstaller через pip, оно не устанавливалось, нашел в интернете ответ такой, что надо откатить pip на раннюю версию, сделал по команде котору привел человек в итоге теперь пишет мне no module named 'pip' как быть? Как вернуть pip?

вот данный ответ, который я нашел:

```
Откати версию PIP до 18.1

 pip install pip==18.1
 Пробуй установить pyinstaller еще раз

 pip install pyinstaller
 Обнови версию PIP до последней

 python -m pip install –upgrade pip
```

Comment: вот ошибка полная Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\valera\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\valera\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Valera\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сталкивался с похожей ошибкой и решил ее жестко и грубо: удалил python и установил снова